# Getter Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, undefined, getter

I have a static getter that grabs a variable inside a class. However, the getter is returning undefined--while getting the variable via `this._title` works great.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ParentClass extends Component {
    _title = "Parent Class";

    static get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
}

export default class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    _title = "Child Class";

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{"By Variable: " + this._title}</p>
                <p>{"By Getter: " + this.title}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the rendered result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqhzB.png)

**Update:**

This is my app, or what is trying to access the class externally:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildClass from './pages/Status';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={byu} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to the P&G System Status Utility</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, select a server:
        </p>
          <p>{"Outside Title: " + ChildClass.title}</p>
          <p>{"Outside Description: " + ChildClass.description}</p>
          <p>{"Outside Author: " + ChildClass.author}</p>
          <ChildClass/>
          <Scanner/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the ChildClass (and ParentClass that it extends)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ParentClass extends Component {
    _title = "Debug";
    _description = "Debug Description";
    _author = "Arbiter";

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
    set title(value) {
        this._title = value;
    }

    get description() {
        return this._description;
    }
    set description(value) {
        this._description = value;
    }

    get author() {
        return this._author;
    }
    set author(value) {
        this._author = value;
    }
}

export default class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    title = "Child Class";

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{"Title Inside: " + this.title}</p>
                <p>{"Description Inside: " + this.description}</p>
                <p>{"Author Inside: " + this.author}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t25b1.png)

(I have absolutely no idea how StackOverflow works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a static getter …

That's exactly the problem. It should not be `static`. You are declaring `ParentClass.title` instead of an instance property.

Comment: What did you think it would do?

Comment: Ok, here is my situation. I have a class, lets say it was my ParentClass. I want to be able to externally access the title variable. I import ParentClass, then I say ParentClass.title -- but that returns undefined. But my ChildClass that extends ParentClass CAN access the getter.

Comment: If that makes sense, the idea is that the child class be able to extend the parent class. While still having other classes access its variables via get set. But, I thought STATIC was the only way to make variables externally accessible.

Comment: Why would you want to make it externally accessible? What other classes would access its value? The only usage you've shown is in `render`, which is a method of an instance (though honestly I'm not sure whether you need a class at all, since everything instance looks the same and all values are constant).

Comment: Updated, for more project clarity.

Comment: It is a very non-standard react app. Built for a very non-standard project. I also need to determine whether this is even possible with React, ES6, or whatever standard this falls under.

Comment: First of all, for simplicity drop all the getters/setters and "private" properties. You absolutely won't need them. Also, you don't need any inheritance between parent and child class - merge them into one.

Comment: Regarding the "outside access", I don't see a good reason to use that. Sure, there are ways to make it possible, but you'd better move those `<p>` elements inside the `<ChildClass>` component and be done with it. That kind of modularisation is why you moved it into its own file, right?

Comment: The reason for the parent/child relationship plays an important role in the overall project. For this example they seem completely redundant, but are very necessary. The `<p>` tag seems like it should be used inside, but it is merely for example reasons, I need the variables externally because I map this data elsewhere.

Comment: Pretend that security and stuff is of no concern. This application will end up built and served inside an Electron package. Even if the end result is horribly insecure, that is fine. I am trying to create a system that is convenient and modular.

Comment: I just need to find a means of accessing class data externally.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*I map this data elsewhere*"? Where does the data come from? Is it actually *data*, not static program code?

Comment: I have a array of Components, all of them share a common parent, meaning I know that they will have a variable (eg. title), I then map through the array and process them. I need to be able to access title from that loop.

Comment: It sounds to me like that should not be an array of component classes, but of actually instantiated objects with different parameters. (`props` in React iirc)